# Delete word/digit/symbol - combinations

Tags: regex, bash, sed, tr

I'm having trouble to delete a word/digit/symbol combinations.

for example:

```
-i en -o nl "stackoverflow" -> "-ien-onlstackoverflow" -> "stackoverflow"

-i nl -o nl "stackflow" -> "-inl-onlstackflow" -> "stackflow"

-o dl -v "question" -c1 -> "-odl-v"question-c1 -> "question"
```

notice that `-v` is followed by nothing, `-i` and `-o` by 2 letters and `-c` by 1 or more digits

I want to have a command that works on each of this combinations because it is for a script and sed didn't work for some reason.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I made a script that accepts flags and I want to delete the flags and there arguments and keep the word that I need for the next steps in my script

Comment: What does your script look like now? How are you handling the arguments? Have you used `shift`?

Comment: Did you consider just using the `getopts` builtin? (Although that won't properly handle the non-standard `-inlonl` syntax, which strikes me as not a great idea.)

Comment: @fangio: What is your expected output?

Comment: @rici, fully agree. unfortunately, the input is a problem: getopts will not see `-c1` in the 3rd example since it follows a non-option argument.

Comment: @glennjackman: `declare -a positional; while ((OPTIND < $#)) do; if getopt "$options" option; then echo handle "$option"; else positional+=${!OPTIND}; ((++OPTIND)); fi; done`

Comment: interesting technique. If the option takes an argument wouldn't you have to increment OPTIND by 2?

Comment: I have asked our teacher and he said we could asume that the last argument given is always the word to use in our script and that is easy for last; do true; done
word=$last

Comment: @glennjackman: No, OPTIND is incremented automatically by getopt for any option, including one with arguments. Only when getopt fails does OPTIND become the caller's responsibility, and then OPTIND points to the first positional argument. My loop then pushes the argument onto the positional array, and increments OPTIND over that argument, so the next call to getopt will start with the argument after the positional argument.

Comment: @fangio: The last positional argument is available much more easily: `"${!#}"`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's#^[-].* \("[[:alnum:]]\{1,\}"\).*#\1#g' 'my_file'
```

where my file have these data